# How to get querystring value while loading the class in django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I need to get the value from querystring which is passing through ajax source. I have class named as xxxx. While loading the class i want to get the value from that querystring. I can able to get the value inside the method using request.GET.get('xxxx') syntax. But i want to get the value while loading the class.

```
sAjaxSource: "/api/helpdesk/?format=json&xxxx=10",
```

I have mentioned the ajax url above.

My api.py file:

```
 class helpdesk(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        """ Here i would like to get the xxxx value"""
```

Inside the method i can easily get it using request.GET.get("xxxx").Plz anyone help me to do this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you specify how you use `helpdesk` class? Do you use tastypie?

Comment: I believe this a case of please tell us what goal you are trying to achieve, because whatever it is, the way you are trying to do it seems wrong.

Comment: Using jquery i can access the class with the url /api/helpdesk/?format=json&xxxx=10 . In this class i need to get the value xxxx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.

`django-tastypie` and similar packages for creating REST APIs leverage the functionality Class-Based Views (CBV) allow, which means that each of those URLs have been assigned the instance method they will use as its view when a request is made to such URL which, in turn, means that the class has been initialized before the `request` object is passed to any methods of the class.

At that point, the class does not know *anything* about your requests.